# Acitvemq is getting timed out for connecting to RHEL7.6 machine

Tags: java, socket.io, activemq-classic, serversocket, sslserversocket

Server being interchanged with different operating system one of them able to connect while other is getting timed out .

The machine which is getting time out in connecting to the server is RHEL7.6 OS , while client machine can connect to the server when it is RHEL 7.5 .